# How to use dynamic link to run query with dynamic variable in Laravel / Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, dynamic, eloquent

I am not sure where to look / what to look for as I am new to HTML / CSS and Laravel / PHP.

I have a function that is returning a collection (of just one item in this case, but I wanted to keep in the count it uses for use later), and I access the object I want in my view as such:

```
Top Vulnerability: @foreach ($tvuln as $object)
                     {{ $object->cve }}
                   @endforeach
```

I want to turn the CVE that is returning into a link and have that link, when pressed take me to another page that runs a query to pull up a list of all hosts with the given CVE.

I am trying to wrap my head around how to do this and could use some guidance in terms of what to search for or how to implement this with Laravel / Eloquent.

Comment: I think may have found what I need to learn about in the laravel http requests documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
@foreach ($tvuln as $object)
    <a href="{{ route(routename..., parameters...) }}">
        {{ $object->cve }}
    </a>
@endforeach
```

For some more info about routes check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes).

Comment: yep that is what I ended up doing: <li><a href="{{ url('vulnerability') }}/{{ $object->cve }}">{{ $object->cve }}: {{ $object->count }}</a><li> ::: inside my foreach

Comment: that ends up making a url that I can use route::get with to deliver to request to my controller, and it names the link with the cve and count. Thanks for replying!!